No Monaco editor suggestions for typescript literals types
I hoped Monaco would behave like vscode, but it currently doesn't. How should I configure it to improve this behaviour? Monaco editor has syntax check, but no suggestion.
declare const fn: (_: 'aaa' | 'bbb') => any;

fn("")



(Monaco editor playground)

Monaco has support for only a few languages built-in (JavaScript, TypeScript, JSON). If you want code completion for other languages you have to create a code completion provider that knows that language.
